# How to force light mode for certain elements in Tailwind

Tags: frontend, tailwind-css, radix-ui

I have a site built using Tailwind CSS, designed almost entirely in dark mode.

Since I use [Radix Colors](https://www.radix-ui.com/colors) (via [windy-radix-palette](https://github.com/brattonross/windy-radix-palette)), which adapt automatically in light/dark mode, I'm switching the entire site to dark mode using the ['class' strategy](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode#toggling-dark-mode-manually) in Tailwind CSS, by applying the `dark` class to my `body` tag:

```
<body class="dark">
```

However, there are certain small sections in the website where I'd like to switch to light mode.

Tailwind CSS allows any element to switch to dark mode using the `dark` class, but a corresponding `light` or `not-dark` class does not seem to exist, which would allow me to switch to light mode in certain places, on a site that's designed to be mostly dark by default.

**How can I force light mode on certain elements that are situated inside a `dark` parent?**

Something like this would be ideal:

```
<div class="not-dark>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try with forcing the color-scheme in css

```css
/* force light if dark */

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  .element {
    color-scheme: dark;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply override the parent style by defining a light theme

```html
<div class="dark:bg-black dark:text-white">
  //Parent element with Dark-mode

  <p class="bg-[white] text-[black]">
    //Child element with Light mode within a Dark-themed parent
  </p>
</div>
```

But if you have multiple similar elements or if you have a predefined set of custom colors, you can create a global color variable in your `globals.css` file

```css
:root {
    --bg-light: #ffffff; /* Light background color */
    --text-light: #000000; /* Light text color */
    
    /* Other custom colors */
  }
```

Then use the css variables in `tailwind.config.js`

```json
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundColor: {
        'not-dark': 'var(--bg-light)',
      },
      textColor: {
        'not-dark': 'var(--text-light)',
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Now use those cusom tailwind classes as shown:

```html
<div class="dark:bg-black dark:text-white">
  //Parent element with Dark-mode

  <p class="bg-not-dark text-not-dark">
    //Child element with Light mode within a Dark-themed parent
  </p>

  <span class="bg-not-dark text-not-dark">
    //Child element with Light mode within a Dark-themed parent
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution is unfortunately not compatible with the Radix Colors' automatic adaptation to light and dark mode.